# Android Publisher API returns 404, when getting subscription, but it exists

Tags: android, api, google-api-client

Last 2 days we are encountering issues with Android Publisher API, which we are using to determine, if user has paid for the app, or not. I am 100% sure, that transaction were paid, but the API returns 404, concretely:

`{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "token",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "The purchase token was not found.",
    "reason" : "purchaseTokenNotFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "The purchase token was not found."
}`

Comment: And of course, i am sure, the token is correct

Comment: We've been experiencing exactly the same problem since around 1800 PST yesterday.

Comment: We are experiencing these problem about 2 days. It is very frustrating, because our system denies using of our application to those affected users.

Comment: Yeah our used to reject, but we've had to modify it to allow the purchase even if google reject the receipt for now. Hoping to find a resolution soon!